# character in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas, and I'm not sure if my question with "Block" is correct.

I have a csv file that contain a sms information. In sms ASCII sms is set to maximum of 160 for a single message, if more than that it will become a maximum of 153 (7 is for User Data Header (UDH)), similarly with unicode character, maximum of 70, and if exceed it will become a maximum of 67 (3 for UDH). I've already concatenate the message into a single row from a single sender that consist multiple parts of messages.

However, my question is, if I append 'Ft0 ' in the beginning of the text message it will add another extra 4 character in the body which also will affect the character of the text message.

For example: let say, a person have 3 part message where the 3rd part of the message length is only 150. If I add the 'Ft0 ' in front of the text message, it will exceed the limit and eventually become 4 part of text messages. If this happened, I will assign a value to a specific column.

Below is my code:

```
df.loc[(df['UDH'].notnull()) & (df['Body'].str.len().gt(153)), 'Double'] = '1'
df.loc[(df['UDH'].notnull()) & (df['Body'].str.len().gt(63)), 'Double'] = '1'
```

I've tried to add the value of 'Ft0 ' in front, however it didn't assign the value to 1 in column 'Double'. (I've counted the number of characters).

Appreciate your suggestion on this and thank you in advance :)

**EDIT**

```
                                Body                             Double
Hello John, How are you doing today? I hope you're fine.           0
Listen, I have a great idea on how to solve this problem. 
Remember the suggestion made by Dr.Robinson on Wednesday 
last Friday? I was thinking we can use the similar
concept and improve the idea to solve our problem.
Do you agree on this?
```

Assuming above in a single row, if I append 'Ft0 ' in front of the text it will assign 1 to column double.

Expected output;

```
         Body                                  Double
Ft0 Hello John, How.....                         1
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible sample data, a sample of what you're getting as output and a sample of what you want it to look like.

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge, as requested, I already update my post :)

Comment: your solution looks fine ... although i dont understand what you are trying to do with the second loc update

Comment: @JoranBeasley it doesn't produce as the expected output, because when I concatenate, the message already exceed the amount of character, hence I was wonder if there's such thing append those 153 character into a 'Block'

Comment: @JoranBeasley any ideas on how to solve my issue? much appreciated

Comment: I still dont understand your issue

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'll summarise my issue, I've concatenate multiple row into a single row, hence the amount of character of that row will be more than 153. If I want to add new text at the beginning of the text 'Ft0 ' now that will change the amount of the character in a SMS concatenation.

Comment: maybe this ? `print(df['Body'].str.extractall("(.{,153})",re.DOTALL))`? (see: https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/VengefulWarmheartedAdware)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209346/discussion-between-syafiq-rosli-and-joran-beasley).